# Narrow a type using a set or array?

Tags: typescript

I have a general `string` that I want to narrow to a generic passed string type `T`.

Trying to use a `T[]` or `Set<T>` to narrow it doesn't work since type `string` isn't assignable to `T`, which is exactly what I'm trying to do. Here's an example:

```js
function inArray<T extends string>(arr: T[], input: string) {
    const optionSet = new Set(arr) // Set<T>
    const [foo] = input.split(','); // foo: string
    
    const inArray =  arr.includes(foo); // Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
    const inSet = optionSet.has(foo); // Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDMBBATughgTwDwAqiApgB5TFgAmAzojVOigOYB8AFFpgFyIEDaAXQA0yMAAcQUXgyZhmASkQBvAFCINiCAgaI442AgDKxKIgC8iMMQDuiE1E6YlAehf3ThVus3awu-mA4OEELMUkoADoacQAbGEcAcmFEhQBuRDdEILgZRhYfDUKtHTMUDGwcMMQudEiUCFiQKmIadhz0zPcAUUw4dF4MZhAAW0ozOGBEKBxxYkRE2RZE5DowODMsGhoYZjAsACNY%20ag4RHEuLDGKdD0pmbmFgkTI4r9dFAcw-UMwB0iABZbdrBTpZXrofqDdDDMZgCb3WbzRb5eQrGBrDY1ba7fZHE5nC7Ya7EW6TaZIp4vVQAXyAA)

Is there any way to set the variable to type `T`? I understand that TS can't ensure that `foo` is of type `T`, but the set/array check are how I'm trying to attain that assurance.

Comment: This is a flaw with the given typings for `Array.prototype.includes` and `Set.prototype.has` (and `Map.prototype.has`). It simply doesn't make sense as of right now, because the point of these methods are to check if some value is in the data structure... Anyways, you should probably just assert for now: `foo as T` and be done with it.

Comment: Methods like `has` and `includes` are too narrowly typed unfortunately - but it sometimes makes sense to warn you that a call would always return `false`. You can however easily widen the type of `arr as string[]` or `optionSet as Set<string>` and call the methods on these.

Comment: Thank you. I'm fine with asserting `foo as T`, but I can't make it fit in `String.prototype.split`'s return type?

Comment: ... A more complete answer would utilize type predicate to lessen the pain of working with these values later: https://tsplay.dev/m3Erkw

Comment: @Bergi Widening is also a good option. Thank you

Comment: @kelsny Excellent! I was going to ask about defining a custom function/generic to help, this is perfect. Thank you

Comment: @kelsny Feel free to post it as an answer. It sufficiently answers my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of right now, the library definitions for `Array.prototype.includes` (and similarly, set/map's `has` method) are too narrow (see [ms/TS#26255](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255) for the discussion). There are a few possible ways to quickly silence the compiler, using assertions.

First, you could assert that `foo` is `T`:

```
const inArray =  arr.includes(foo as T);
```

Or you could widen the type of `arr` to be `string[]`:

```
const inArray =  (arr as string[]).includes(foo);
```

Even asserting the split array here would do the trick:

```
const [foo] = input.split(',') as T[];
```

However, with the first 2 methods, you would still have to deal with `foo` having the wrong type. My recommendation would be to use [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) which are a form of user-defined type guards.

```
const isElementInArray = <T>(arr: T[], element: unknown): element is T => arr.includes(element as T);
const isElementInSet = <T>(set: Set<T>, element: unknown): element is T => set.has(element as T);
```

Then you can let TS know that if the guard returned true, `foo` has the type `T`:

```
const inArray = isElementInArray(arr, foo);
const inSet = isElementInSet(optionSet, foo);

arr[0] = foo; // invalid
optionSet.add(foo); // invalid

if (inArray) {
    // now it's ok
    arr[0] = foo; // or whatever
}

if (inSet) {
    // now it's ok
    optionSet.add(foo); // or whatever
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAogGwKYFtVigSTAQQCdCBDATxgF4YAeAFQD4AKE4gLhjoG0BdAGhio0mbBwCuYANZgQAdzABKDkIxZYCTlQYxWhAHRwwwZGIAmqCExUjYJCJwUBuAFChI6pMLV4AyqljU9MwQ-hx+UEEC1mriUjLySoJe2PD2dFowIVB6ABZ2Vsm2aU7OzgBmEsBQcODwBMTk9IIAHlBYpvbQhIYA5sy6HNz8dQAOYlAcXb0KMADezjCLMG7QMCAj1eDhVDBgqLIw4SzEMwD0p4f+QQtLK7BcZSAgPDuGY9kQI8hwUEwA5Hw-k4YOcYI8QJMoN0wD1SktluBVoYiKQKNQEChVNg8CjyMdCAJwSV4Xc6tt0Z4sbgwEd1psaf5CU8SjdFrouAAGF7UcGOEEXQwANxI31MrLWGxqDOyJFMpiYRL5oKFIrgYvFcDKMCYyIaZBm83h8NB8XgUD+9hAknF8PZXJ2vP5a0IMFkeTagtQhHFAF84UtNdrDOEDTalia5GaLWtrUalnSpeE9LL5YqnSAXW6SB6vb7nD6gA)